# Stop a JFX embedded YouTube video

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a JPanel component containing a JFXPanel with a browser that embedds a YouTube video. I'm using the videos embed URL from YouTube (i.e. https://www.youtube.com/embed/W-J2OYN9fF8?autoplay=true&controls=0).

I can add the JPanel (`VideoPlayer`) to a surrounding component without any problem. However - when I remove the VideoPlayer I would also like to stop the YouTube-player. As of now - it keeps playing in the background (with annoying sound). I'm guessing I have to get inside the JFX thread somehow... So, if someone could please help me with code to put in the `stopTrailer()` method - I'd be very grateful!

Here's my current code. For those who are looking for a simple way to embed a JFX YouTube player in a normal JPanel - this works great - appart from the limitations above...

```
public class VideoPlayer extends JPanel {  
private Stage stage;
private WebView browser;
private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
private WebEngine webEngine;
private String videoUrl;

public VideoPlayer(String url){ 
    this.videoUrl = url;
    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    createScene();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 560));
    add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}  
private void createScene() {    
    PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stage = new Stage();

            stage.setTitle("Video");
            stage.setResizable(true);

            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,80,20);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            //Set up the embedded browser:
            browser = new WebView();
            webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load(videoUrl);

            ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();
            children.add(browser);                     

            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);  
        }
    });
}

public void stopTrailer() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was actually really simple. I put the following in the stopTrailer method.

```
public void stopTrailer() { 
    PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            remove(jfxPanel);
            webEngine.load(null);
        }
    });
}
```

What it actually does is to reload the browser `webEngine` to the "address" null. And removes the panel. It seems a bit weird to me cause I would interpret this code as the start of a second thread - without access to the first one. Perhaps someone could explain just how this works?